# Moving the images to a different position

Tags: html, css, image

I've been trying to move the small images (thumbnails) but it won't move. It just stays fixed to the left. I've tried giving it an div id and set the margins for it but it doesn't work.

Here are the codes:

JavaScript

```
function showImage(imgName) {
    document.getElementById('largeImg').src = imgName;
    showLargeImagePanel();
    unselectAll();
}
function showLargeImagePanel() {
    document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function unselectAll() {
    if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
    if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
function hideMe(obj) {
    obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

CSS

```
#largeImgPanel {
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100; 
    top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
}
```

Html body

```
<body>
    <img src="images/small1.png" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('images/large1.jpg');" />
    <img src="images/small2.jpg" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('images/large2.jpg');" />
    <img src="3_small.jpeg" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('3_large.jpeg');" />

    <div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
        <img id="largeImg" margin: 0; padding: 0;" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: How did you try to move it?

Comment: @Aioros put the images into a div then gave it an id then I tried setting its margin in css style

Comment: @Elvain you are trying to move image into the div `largeImgPanel`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 this is what it looks like with the current code: http://jsfiddle.net/vKa5n/ (sorry the images are stored on my comp)

Comment: Don't know if that's what you're looking for, but it works fine (apparently). http://jsfiddle.net/nYavS/

Comment: @optim no im just moving the small jpg images.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Moving from/to where?

Comment: You can use custom images with size of your choice. See here: http://placehold.it/

Comment: @MelanciaUK the images are stuck on the far left and I tried moving the small images/thumbnails to the center or elsewhere but it won't move.

Comment: Do you mean the three small images or the one inside the largeImgPanel?

Comment: @Aioros the three small images

Comment: A quick way - and if you know exactly how many images and their dimensions - is to wrap them on a div with fixed width/height and position it absolutely (playing with top/left/margin-top/margin-left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's the three `img`s tags you're talking about, you have to set their style. Something like:

```
<img src="images/small1.png" class="smallimg" onclick="showImage('images/large1.jpg');" />
<img src="images/small2.jpg" class="smallimg" onclick="showImage('images/large2.jpg');" />
<img src="3_small.jpeg" class="smallimg" onclick="showImage('3_large.jpeg');" />
```

and

```
.smallimg {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    /* or whatever position/top/left values you need */
}
```

Or if you want them centered, you could do something like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="images/small1.png" class="smallimg" onclick="showImage('images/large1.jpg');" />
    <img src="images/small2.jpg" class="smallimg" onclick="showImage('images/large2.jpg');" />
    <img src="3_small.jpeg" class="smallimg" onclick="showImage('3_large.jpeg');" />
</div>
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem. He wants them centered in the page (or something like that). What you've tried to achieve here could be done by just using display (inline, inline-table, etc). No float needed.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer with another simple possibility. Let's see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on my comment. Maybe you can go through this option:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.bit-101.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/ball.png" alt="" />
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41P44yRoAPL._SL75_SS50_.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41B9Qbj2CBL._SL75_SS50_.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    height: 50px; /* img height */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px; /* half of the img height */
    margin-left: -75px; /* half of the img width's total */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container > img
{
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qFmhf/